# Проблема с выводом в консоль крестов (консольная графика c помощью символа #) на c#

Tags: c#, изображения, консоль

Мне необходимо сделать правильный вывод в консоль с параметрами width, columns и rows как указано на рисунке:[image: Кресты в консоли]

Мой код:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("width:");
    int W = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("columns:");
    int C = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("rows:");
    int R = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
        Picture(W);
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}

static void Picture(int width)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    #");

        if (i == 1)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < width; j++)
            {
                Console.Write('#');
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Такой вопрос: Как мне правильно вывести рисунок крестов в колонки и строки по заданным параметрам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с функцией, если кому будет нужнo:

```
static void DrawCross(int width, int columns, int rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows * width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns * width; j++)
            {
                if (((i + width / 2 + 1) % width == 0) || ((j + width / 2 + 1) % width == 0))
                    Console.Write("#");
                else
                    Console.Write(" ");

                if ((j + 1) % width == 0)
                    Console.Write(" ");
            }

            if ((i + 1) % width == 0)
                Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```